# Multiplicar dos valores de un modelo en una variable en el controlador y enviar a la vista, ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Cuento con un modelo donde tengo dos valores, la cantidad de un producto y el precio, y quiero obtener (Total=Cantidad*Precio) esta operación quiero que se haga en el controlador.

El Modelo.
Estoy en duda de si es necesario un "public int Total{ get; set; }"

```
public class MOrdenCompraCalculo
    {
        public int IdOrdenCompra { get; set; }
        public string Proveedor { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string UnidadMedida { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public int Precio { get; set; } 
    }
```

El Controlador.

La operación de la multiplicación precio y cantidad, quiero que se haga en el controlador y el resultado lo envíe a la vista para poder ser visualizada en la tabla.

```
public class MOrdenCompraCalculoController : Controller
    {
        public List<MOrdenCompraCalculo> GetDatosOrdenCompraCalculo()
        {
            var DatosOrdenCompraCalculo = new List<MOrdenCompraCalculo>();
            DatosOrdenCompraCalculo.Add(new MOrdenCompraCalculo()
            {
                IdOrdenCompra = 1,
                Proveedor = "Maestro",
                Descripcion = "Perno de 1/2 x 3/4",
                UnidadMedida = "Und",
                Cantidad = 10,
                Precio = 5,


            });
            DatosOrdenCompraCalculo.Add(new MOrdenCompraCalculo()
            {
                IdOrdenCompra = 2,
                Proveedor = "Sodimac",
                Descripcion = "Arandela Zincada de 3/4",
                UnidadMedida = "Und",
                Cantidad = 2,
                Precio = 1,
            });
            return DatosOrdenCompraCalculo;
        }

public IActionResult ListadoOrdenCompraCalculo()
        {
            ViewBag.ID = "IdOrdenCompra";
            ViewBag.PD = "Proveedor";
            ViewBag.DE = "Descripcion";
            ViewBag.UM = "UnidadMedida";
            ViewBag.CA = "Cantidad";
            ViewBag.PR = "Precio";
            ViewBag.TO = "Total";
            var ListadoOrdenCompraCalculo = GetDatosOrdenCompraCalculo();
            ViewBag.MOrdenCompraCalculo = ListadoOrdenCompraCalculo;
            return View();
        }
```

Vista.

Obtener el resultado del controlador.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-danger">
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.ID</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.PD</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.DE</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.UM</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.CA</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.PR</strong></center></th>
            <th><center><strong>@ViewBag.TO</strong></center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MOrdenCompraCalculo)
        {
            <tr class="table table-bordered">
                <td align="center">@item.IdOrdenCompra</td>
                <td align="center">@item.Proveedor</td>
                <td align="center">@item.Descripcion</td>
                <td align="center">@item.UnidadMedida</td>
                <td align="center">@item.Cantidad</td>
                <td align="center">@item.Precio</td>
                <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

---

@Yussef Gracias por seguir ayudándome, es que el ejercicio propuesto me pide que los cálculos se haga en el controlador, por eso insisto en eso.
Hice lo que me dijiste creé la propiedad public int Total {get;set;} en el modelo, al añadir en el Total=Cantidad*precio me sale un error que dice "El nombre 'Cantidad' y 'Precio' no existe en el contexto actual". No sé si te referías a eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el modelo creas una función que se llame GetTotal

```
public class MOrdenCompraCalculo
{
    public int IdOrdenCompra { get; set; }
    public string Proveedor { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string UnidadMedida { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; } 
    public int GetTotal(){
         return Cantidad * Precio;
    }
 
}
```

Luego en tu vista solo tienes que llamar a la propiedad

```
<tr class="table table-bordered">
   <td align="center">@item.IdOrdenCompra</td>
   <td align="center">@item.Proveedor</td>
   <td align="center">@item.Descripcion</td>
   <td align="center">@item.UnidadMedida</td>
   <td align="center">@item.Cantidad</td>
   <td align="center">@item.Precio</td>
   <td align="center">@item.GetTotal()</td>
   <td align="center"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Pero esa operación, como lo puedo hacer en el controlador? y lo envíe a la vista.

Comment: @lembda1 ¿Has intentado realizar los cambios que el buen usuario Yussef ha compartido?

Comment: Si hice los cambios y funciona, pero lo que yo buscaba era que esa operación (Total=Cantidad*Precio) se haga en el controlador y sea enviado a la vista.

Comment: @lembda1 Es más o menos lo mismo, creas una propiedad  public int Total {get;set;} y cuando ingresas los valores de Cantidad y Precio en el controlador, ahora también seteas Total con Cantidad * Valor. Pero, la mejor manera de hacerlo es como está en mi respuesta original

Comment: @Yussef gracias por seguir ayudándome, es que el ejercicio me pide que los cálculos se haga en el controlador, por eso insisto en eso. Hice lo que me dijiste creé la propiedad public int Total {get;set;} en el modelo, al añadir en el Total=Cantidad*precio me sale un error que dice "El nombre 'Cantidad' y 'Precio' no existe en el contexto actual"